# Updating the Decision Surfaces of a trained LDA classifier for Face Recognition

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis, pattern-recognition

I want to perform an experiment where I compare two classifiers based on LDA:

- The first classifier is trained on all images of one half of the total amount of persons in the data set
- The second classifier is trained on one image per person on the other half of the persons

e.g: 6 persons (A,B,C,D,E,F) -> C1 on all images of A,B,C and C2 on one image of D,E,F
(images are 100x100 pixels, so the dimension of the input is 10000)

The test-set consists of all images that remain of D,E,F.

Basicly I train C1, which learns a projection matrix that best separates the classes (LDA reduces the dimensionality here, the test-samples get projected to this subspace a.k.a "Face-space" *[from now on F1-space]* and classification takes place in this subspace where we also have a **decision surface**(hyperplane))

Now what I do not know how to approach is the following; Once I have trained C1 how do I update/change the decision surface in F1 using the images C2 was trained on?

**The purpose of comparing these two is to explore whether it is better to use a classifier which captures realistic variation but is trained on the wrong persons or the classifier trained on the right persons but with low variation**

Let me know if I need to clarify anything, I'll update this question if it isn't clear enough!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 04/07/2020:

This is a 2D plot of F1 with the Decision boundaries plotted;
[image: 2D subspace with DB]

Below a 2D plot of the data C2 was trained on, projected into F1, with the old Decision boundaries plotted (not updated).
[image: unseen persons in F1 with old DB]

Now these 2D plots are just for visualization, let's say I have more than 3 classes, say 100, Samples will be projected into a 99-Dimensional subspace. I was thinking of using a 1NN classifier in that space with mahalanobis distance to the nearest centroid, *opinions on this approach are more than welcome!!*

But I would still like to update the Decision boundaries in the 2D case. These bounds are computed using the shared covariance matrix and class means, so would it make sense to assign the "new" means (data from C2, second figure) to different "old" means (data from c1, first figure) and recompute the means but keep the covariance?

It's obvious in this 2D case that C1 is horrible at seperating the unseen persons of C2, but that's because F1 is overfit on 3 persons, with more classes and in a higher dimensional subspace the seperation will likely be better [that's what I'm researching at the moment].